# SVG triangle separator with image background

Tags: html, css, svg, css-shapes

Well, I'm trying to create an SVG section separator. It worked like this:

```html
<section id="section1">
</section>
<svg width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
  <path d="M0 0 L50 100 L100 0 Z" />
</svg>
<section id="section2">
</section>
```

[image]

So far, so good. But now, I want to add a background to section1, including the SVG "pick", in example:

[image]

All I've accomplished is (really bad results):

Adding a

```
background: url(img)
```

to the  element

[image]

And:

Justing adding a BG to section1

[image]

Comment: You can do this with CSS only and automatically for each section, without the need for the extra markup... any reason you specifically want to do it with an SVG?

Comment: Well, I wanted to use SVG to learn a bit more, but I don't have a reason. How would you do it with CSS?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an approach using the same code as your example but the svg path is changed to an inverted triangle and absolutely positioned to the bottom of the section:

```css
#section1{
  position:relative;
  background:url('http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg');
  background-size:cover;
  height:200px;
}
svg{
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-10px; left:0;
  width:100%; height:100px;
  display:block;
}
```

```html
<section id="section1">
  <svg width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 102" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <path d="M0 0 L50 90 L100 0 V100 H0" fill="#2A80B9" />
  </svg>
</section>
```

Comment: Yes! Works as a charm. thanks! https://jsfiddle.net/JorgeAnzola/v49ghtzf/1/

Answer (score 4):

Variant with a gradient:

```css
.element {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(-164deg, transparent 75%, #2A80B9 75%, #2A80B9 100%), linear-gradient(164deg, transparent 75%, #2A80B9 75%, #2A80B9 100%), url(http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg);
  background-size: auto, auto, cover;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Comment: @МаксимЛенский, come to my chat room. Let's talk.. http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52027/communication-with-the-yuri

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I'm well aware this doesn't answer the question directly, however the questioner stated in the comments that they're interested in a non-SVG solution as well, and for reasons explained later in the post, it's a much better way to tackle this problem.

```css
section {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg');
  background-size: cover;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
}
section:after {
  border-color: transparent #2a80b9;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 90px 300px 0; /* the first value is the height of the triangles, the second is half the width of the parent container */
  content: '';
  height: 10px; /* this is the height of the solid color underneath the triangles */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<section></section>
```

This solution works by absolutely placing an element at the end of every section, overlaying that and rendering the required shapes by use of borders - by giving the top border a transparent color.

This has the following qualities compared to an SVG solution:

- there's no need for extra markup in every section because of the universally applying rule
- that also means it's easier to maintain, because you don't have to go through multiple html files, looking for stray SVGs (which is why style should go in CSS and not markup in the first place)
- changing the shape of the SVG requires changing several values, while you only need to change a single CSS value for anything you want to do. The CSS rules are also much more human-readable than the SVG multi-line anchor points (this might be subjective)

Comment: Downside of this solution: You need to know the exact size of the container. The triangle/border always has a pixel-size defined by the border width.

Comment: @Philipp you're not wrong, however you can help this along in some situations by using percentage-based values or vw/vh - the latter is especially viable using vh for the bottom border if you need an element to span the entire viewport width, and you want to retain its aspect ratio like in the example from the question.

Answer (score 0):

Variant with two triangles

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.element {  
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
}
.element:before,
.element:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; bottom: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
.element:before{
  left: 0;  
  border-width: 100px 0 0 55vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #00f;
}
.element:after{
  right: 0;  
  border-width: 0 0 100px 55vw;
  border-color: transparent transparent #00f transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```

Variant clip-path

```css
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.element {  
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/k8BtMvj.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
}
.element:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #00f;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 95%, 100% 40%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 40%);
  clip-path: polygon(50% 95%, 100% 40%, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 40%);
}
```

```html
<div class="element"></div>
```